# Invocar un método de una Applet desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando la migración de una aplicación que entre otras cosas tiene una applet de la que se invocan varios métodos en ciertos momentos. Esto me funciona correctamente en Internet Explorer, pero cuando pretendo realizar lo mismo en mi nueva aplicación no funciona. La applet si que se está ejecutando en un principio ya que al iniciar la página me aparecen los mensajes necesarios para darle a ejecutar, pero es el momento en el que invoco a los métodos cuando falla. El código de prueba es el siguiente:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Call Applet" onclick="arrancar();"/>
      <p>      
         <object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
               id="idApplet" width="0" height="0"
               codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,0,0">
               <param name="code" value="com.matchmind.clientesfd.applet.ClienteSFDApplet" />
               <param name="archive" value="./sfd_jar/appletSFD.jar" />
      <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4" />                         
         </object>                 
   </p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 
  function arrancar() {
   var applet = document.getElementById('idApplet');
      applet.iniciarCheckEstadoSimple();
      
   idApplet.arrancarServicio();

   console.log(document.applets.item(0).arrancarServicio());
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En el método "arrancar" pruebo a invocar los métodos de diferentes maneras pero ninguna funciona, siempre da un error que dice El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método. En la aplicación a migrar no da este error y la forma en la que realizan las invocaciones es a través del getElementById. ¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser esto? Gracias.

Esta es la depuración por consola de applet:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si la muestro por consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sólo por descartar cosas, ¿has probado con el tag <APPLET> en vez de <OBJECT>?

Comment: Si, además necesito que sea con el tag Object puesto que esto luego va en realidad en un proyecto de Angular 2 y ahi no se admite el tag APPLET, solo que mientras lo consigo por comodidad lo pruebo en este HTML básico @Kiko_L

Comment: Estás llamando a idApplet.arrancarServicio(); pero idApplet no es ninguna variable definida. Tendría que ser applet.arrancarServicio();

Comment: Tal y como está el código ahora mismo falla en la línea "applet.iniciarCheckEstadoSimple();", siendo iniciarCheckEstadoSimple un método de la applet, las dos últimas líneas en este caso no se llegan a ejecutar, pero las he quedado puesta puesto que son opciones que también probé y tampoco funcionaron. @Kiko_L

Comment: ¿Puedes abrir la consola e inspeccionar el objeto "applet" antes de ejecutar iniciarCheckEstadoSimple()?

Comment: Si, te las he añadido a la pregunta para que las puedas ver @Kiko_L

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83934/discussion-between-cristina-extremera-romero-and-kiko-l).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay varios problemas:

1. En la linea 22 hay un error, no existe en JS el objeto idApplet, asi que no podemos acceder a el. Si hace falta hacer esto, primero tenemos que crear este objeto.
2. Objeto applet no esta cargado, existe solo de tipo "object" y evidentemente no tiene ni propiedades, ni funciones con los nombres indicados.
3. Hay que cargar primero el applet y cuando esta cargado habilitar el boton.
4. Hay que revisar permisos y si esta instalado el Java, sino no hay nadie que interpreta este objeto. JavaScript no es Java.